# Line graph of square lattice

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Is it possible to create a [line graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph) of an n by n square lattice? If so what would it look like and does it have a specific name? I've tried drawing it manually and ended with sideways squares tiled with triangles, looking almost like the $(3^2,4,3,4)$ lattice however I believe this is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trivial in *Mathematica*:

```
g = GridGraph[{3, 4}]
```

[image]

```
LineGraph[g]
```

[image]

Here is the line graph for a $10 \times 10$ grid graph:

[image]

No specific name that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

I drew it out, and the best way I can describe it is the following:

You take the lattice and rotate it 45 degrees. Then for alternating tiles, you draw both diagonals to make it a complete graph.

The whole thing looks almost like a grid of $K_4$ complete graphs stitched together.

**EDIT:** You can find it on page 2 of [this PDF](https://courses.physics.ucsd.edu/2019/Fall/physics239/LECTURES/line_graphs.pdf).